# Adding TeamCity build configurations to (proper) source control

Tags: version-control, automation, teamcity

We have over 100 build configurations in Team City, and I've come to realize over the past few months that these assets are just as important (if not more so) than the actual project assets (code, config, etc) we are delivering.

To that end, I know TC provides it's own build configuration version control but to me that seems a bit low on features - for example if a build stops working it would be really good to be able to diff the actual XML build configurations in my favorite diff tool rather than rely on TC's built in one, or to be able to view differences across a longer time frame than simply against the previous state.

Obviously this can be handled manually by extracting the build definition and committing, and then applying self disciple to always do this when you change the definition. Can anyone suggest a more joined up approach? We're using TeamCity Enterprise v8.0.5

Comment: I just checked one of my TeamCity instances and I see history going back to when a build configuration was created nearly a year ago and I can diff the XML within TeamCity at any point along about 30 changes, another configuration I only get one entry. I don't know which version of TeamCity versioning was added in, but that might be why you're not seeing more than the current and one more.

Comment: Well I can definitively confirm that 8 doesn't allow that...

Comment: I was looking at an instance running 8.0.3. It shows "Last edited one month ago by Jonathon Rossi (view history)". Does the "view history" link show up for you? Try going to `/admin/admin.html?item=audit&actionTypeSet=33`.

Comment: @JonathonRossi - weird, I can't see the view history link. Just the "view change" link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an interim solution before you upgrade to TeamCity 9, you could write a scheduled job to run every 10mins (or even every minute) and automatically commit the changes to a new repository. I'd use a new repository so TeamCity doesn't ever try and trigger off the commits.

I don't know what OS or VCS you are using, but you'd just need to commit all XML files so you get `project-config.xml`, build type XML, and plugin config, you don't want `.properties` files as the build number files will change after every build.

- `<TeamCityData>/config/projects/**/*.xml`

If you are using Git you could easily just init a repo in the `projects` directory, add a `.gitignore` for anything other than `*.xml`, and run `git add .` and `git commit -m "Build configuration settings were edited"` as a scheduled job.

Answer (score 4):

Can you upgrade to TeamCity 9? TeamCity now has built in support to sync the build configurations to Git or Mercurial.

https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/whatsnew/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTLeCrdxGIw

Comment: Yeah potentially that would be a goer - though ideally I'd like to do an interim solution